# multiple setcookie() calls produce 502 error

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, gravityforms

I have a wordpress installation with Gravityforms Nested Forms plugin. Form entries are stored in a cookie (JSON encoded). Every new entry causes a setcookie() call.

Now, when I manually add more than 6 new entries in one run by using the plugins methods, it produces a 502 Bad Gateway error. I figured out that the problem are the 6 (or more) setcookie() calls, because if I comment it out it works fine.

Any help?

If I test on another environment (simple loop with setcookie() calls) it works.

Comment: _“Form entries are stored in a cookie (JSON encoded)”_ - by the plugin itself, or by you? Because that sounds like a rather bad idea to begin with …

Comment: Have you checked what the error log has to say? I’m guessing you are simply running into a request or response size limit somewhere.

Comment: @04FS this is done by the plugin.
Error logs are empty, they say nothing about that issue

Comment: _Which_ logs did you check? This error usually occurs in situations, where you have one server acting as a gateway or proxy for another. We don’t know what setup you are working with here.

Comment: I checked PHP logs and Apache logs

Comment: @04FS It only stores the entry IDs (not the entry values) and prevents loading arbitrary entry IDs. You most "own" the entry to view its values. 

Natha, we'll be happy to dig into your issue via support: https://gravitywiz.com/support/ 